# Source for reliable information on transit rules at a specific airport?

Tags: transit, airport-security, connecting-flights

Two important factors in determining the complexity and viability of a connection are:

1. Are there airside connections between place A and place B?
2. Even if there are, do I still have to go through security?

That seems to vary a lot from airport to airport and sometimes even from terminal to terminal without any obvious rhyme or reason. For example on my most recent trip I had to go through security in Istanbul and London Heathrow but not in Washington or Vienna (despite all being airside connections). In Boston you can get airside from Terminal E to C but not to A or B.

This information seems to be very difficult and tedious to find. Most airport's websites don't provide it. Best I have come up with are random Google searches or plowing through different forums like this here. It's time consuming, not very reliable and the success rate isn't great either.

Question: What's the most reliable or easiest way to determine whether an airside connection is available and whether another security check is required?

Comment: I like the question.  It's in a similar spirit to [my recent question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175102/4171) on which [you commented](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175102/does-international-to-domestic-connection-in-canada-require-baggage-claim-and-dr#comment438451_175102) "...There may be a few exceptions but it feels like too much work go find them. **It can also vary from day to day**...."

Answer (score 4):

To find out whether an airside transfer is available for the particular set of flights you need to know which gates they will use and in many cases gates are not allocated till shortly before the plane arrives, and in those cases where it is known well before it can be changed at short notice.
And while airports try to keep flights in the same section of the airport so security measures and transfers will follow the same rules, it is not always possible.
I'd say it is impossible to make a site covering that search function.

The same goes for going through security between flights, maybe even stronger, as airports do not seem to hesitate to have people go through an extra security check if it allows them to use a certain gate which may otherwise be unavailable.

So my answer is a 'No, not possible' as there are too many variables and those can change on very short notice.

Comment: +1 I sort of agree with you. Just noting that it *is* possible, just insanely complicated and tricky, and it'll take way too much cooperation and work with all other countries to put together something this extensive.

Comment: While it is possible in theory, there will be too many  flights that do not follow the rules as gate changes are made. No reputable site will take any responsability for the information and non reputable sites are worthless.

Comment: The correct answer is **'No, not possible'** so indeed this is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not looking for that level of detail. Just Terminal to Terminal would easily cover 95%+ of all cases. Like the example for Boston that I put in my question.  This is simply due to the layout of the airport and it doesn't change.